# do not pass correct settings.xml to Maven Release Plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

i have the following issue with eclipse , i am running an mvn install , 
try to build my project.

no idea what do with this error

please help

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building superman 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hpi-plugin:1.95:validate (default-validate) @ superman ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ superman ---
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
Build with Maven 3.0.4 or later. Maven 3.0 through 3.0.3 inclusive do not pass correct settings.xml to Maven Release Plugin.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.032s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 04 11:24:21 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/355M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:enforce (enforce-maven) on project superman: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

That means simply that you are using an older Maven version. Based on the rule you have to use Maven 3.0.5+ that's the problem. The problem with Maven 3.0...3.0.3 had problems with informations from settings.xml to the release plugin which produces problems.

Comment: i am using eclipse , but i have download maven 3.2.3 in my workstation, how do i go on fixing this issue. in eclipse

Comment: i have install maven plugin in eclipse, i have the latest maven 3.2.3, i have set that to my environment variables,

Comment: i have install maven plugin in eclipse, i have the latest maven 3.2.3, i have set that to my environment variables, 

i am still getting the same error ... is there a settings in eclipse that i need to change so it build with maven 3.0.4 or later ?

please let me know

Comment: Have you checked with new installation of Maven on command line to build this project?

Answer (score 0):

so after all that , you have to go to

window> preferences > maven > installations > and change the settings in there to the new install on your work station . that why eclipse is going to use the new maven 3.2.3

issue solved